# How can I remove \xa0$ from my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to clean my data which contains by making the columns[1:] float types.

```
for col_i in new_col_titles[1:]:
    df[col_i] = df[col_i].astype(float)
```

However, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\xa0$ 25,507,036'
```

I have tried to use `df = df.replace('\x0$','')` but I have so far had no luck

Comment: Can you try `df[col_i] = df[col_i].str.replace('\x0$', '').astype(float)`?

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape

Comment: I missed `a` in `\xa0$`

Comment: still returns \xa0$ 25,507,036 when I did \xao it did this error though "could not convert string to float: '$ 25,507,036'"

Comment: I managed to remove the \xao but it now shows this $ 25507036', '$ 21550568', '$ 21576850' when i do     print (df.astype(str).values.tolist())   But I cant seem to use replace to remove the dollar sign

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a multistep process, Im sure someone can clean this up a little but for anyone else who is stuck by this:

```
   for col_i in new_col_titles:
        df[col_i] = df[col_i].astype(str)
        df[col_i] = df[col_i].str.replace('\xa0', '', regex=True)
        df[col_i] = df[col_i].str.replace('$', '', regex=True)
```